# How do I permanently assign the value of a field in Mongodb to the value of another field in the same document

Tags: mongodb

In the document below I want the field display_image to be permanently assigned (not programmatically assigned) to images1.images[0] as shown here:

```
{
  "images1":
[
  {
    "color":"blue1",
    "images":["blue1-mom-jeans-3.1.png","blue1-mom-jeans-3.2.png"],        
  }
],
"display_image": images1[0].images[0]
  }
```

Comment: You can do an update operation using the Update with Aggregation Pipeline.

Comment: I don't want to do this programmatically. I want display_image to be permanently assigned to images1.images[0].

Comment: You can use a Change Stream - that is whenever the images field is created/updated, the display_image is automatically created/updated with the images1.images[0].

Comment: @prasad: I am not familiar with Change Stream.

Comment: Its a MongoDB database feature - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @prasad_ above this can be done via update query with aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
 {
   $addFields: {
    "display_image": {
      $arrayElemAt: [
       "$images1",
        0
       ]
      }
     }
   },
   {
     $addFields: {
    "display_image": {
      $arrayElemAt: [
      "$display_image.images",
       0
      ]
    }
   }
  }
])
```

Explained:

Extract the value from images1[0].images[0] and assigne to the new field called "display_image" , if you add {multi:true} the operation will update all documents in your database.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ntr410lgfXu)

( Please, note this is supported in mongodb 4.2+ versions)